# Converting JSON to HTML with XSLT3.0

Tags: json, xslt-3.0

I am trying to convert json to html with XSLT3.0.
I have a JSON document similar to:

```
{
    "ID":1234,
    "Title":"Garden Club",
    "Created":1677598782,
    "Modified":1677796144,
    "SystemChanged":"Greenhouse",
    "SystemChangedID":51007,
    "SystemsAffected":["Greenhouse", "Garden"],
    "SystemsAffectedID":[51007,89756],
    "IncidentType":"Maintenance",
    "Description":"Greenhouse fan motor will be replaced.",
    "StartDate":1677794400,
    "Feed":[{
        "id":106799743,
        "commentBy":"Don Knotts",
        "dateCreated":1677796144,
        "dateUpdated":1677796144,
        "content":"Work has been completed successfully. Fan working as expected"
    }]
}
```

My XSL stylesheet looks like this.  This is what I am using to convert the JSON to XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs">
    
    <xsl:variable name="reportjson" select="unparsed-text('/_resources/js/issue.json')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="reportxml" select="json-to-xml($reportjson, map { 'liberal': true() })"/>

    <xsl:template name="page-content">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$reportxml"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML output looks like this.

```
<array><map>
    <number key="ID">1234</number>
    <string key="Title">Garden Club</string>
    <number key="Created">1677598782</number>
    <number key="Modified">1677796144</number>
    <string key="SystemChanged">Greenhouse</string>
    <number key="SystemChangedID">51007</number>
    <array key="SystemsAffected">
        <string>Greenhouse</string>
        <string>Garden</string>
    </array>
    <array key="SystemsAffectedID">
        <number>51007</number>
        <number>89756</number>
    </array>
    <string key="IncidentType">Maintenance</string>
    <string key="Description">Greenhouse fan motor will be replaced.</string>
    <number key="StartDate">1677794400</number>
    <array key="Feed"><map>
        <number key="id">106799743</number>
        <string key="commentBy">Don Knotts</string>
        <number key="dateCreated">1677796144</number>
        <number key="dateUpdated">1677796144</number>
        <string key="content">Work has been completed successfully. Fan working as expected</string>
        </map>
    </array>
    </map>
</array>
```

How do I convert this to an HTML table using template matches? I tried to use template matches.  The problem is that it doesn't seem to be selecting anything.

```
    <xsl:template match="array"><table><xsl:apply-templates/></table></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map"><tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="number|string"><td><xsl:apply-templates select="*/text()"/></td></xsl:template>
```

I have used xsl:for-each before.  This would be similar to doing the below.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$reportxml/array">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="map">
            <tr>...</tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json-to-xml function produces elements in a certain namespace so set e.g. `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` if you expect your templates e.g. `xsl:template match="array"` to match the element(s) from that namespace.